# TableView JavaFX - Resize only one column

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I want to apply the ResizePolicy in only a column, in the case the column "Progresso". The solution that I found in internet is put this command in the controller: tabela.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY). But it wanted to have the same effect in the cited column.

FXML code:

```
<TableView fx:id="tabela" minWidth = "773.0">
            <columns>
                <TableColumn fx:id="numero" prefWidth="35.0" minWidth="35.0" maxWidth="35.0" text="Nº " />
                <TableColumn fx:id="nome" prefWidth="183.0" minWidth="183.0" maxWidth="183.0" text="Nome" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="tamanho" prefWidth="76.0" minWidth="76.0" maxWidth="76.0" text="Tamanho" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="velocidade" prefWidth="76.0" minWidth="76.0" maxWidth="76.0" text="Velocidade" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="tempo_estimado" prefWidth="120.0" minWidth="120.0" maxWidth="120.0" text="Tempo Estimado" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="estado" prefWidth="282.0" minWidth="282.0" maxWidth="282.0" text="Estado" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="progresso" prefWidth="282.0" text="Progresso" />
            </columns>
</TableView>
```

Comment: What exactly would you like to do? Every column of your table have a given width and by using "maxWidth" and "minWidth" properties you can't resize any of it. Enlarging "progresso" column is impossible because of the other columns' constraints.

Comment: My idea is to keep all the others columns with the fixed size, only the column "Progress" change your size

Comment: How can it be possible, if by changing the size of the particular column, you change the size of the corresponding column?